# How to read character by character from text file?

Tags: asp.net

How to read character by character in line from text file?

Comment: In future, you should tag your question with the language you are using e.g `c#`, `vb.net` You should also provide some code that you have tried to use that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [StraemReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) class. It has a [Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx) method that reads the next character from the input stream and advances the character position by one character. (Overrides TextReader.Read().)

For example:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
     while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
     {
         char c = (char)sr.Read();
     }
}
```